# PHP printing blank page

Tags: php, printing, pdf-generation

I use printer extension in PHP. I use virtual printer print PDF. It works with browser, but prints a blank page when use PHP code !!

This is code

```
<?php
//$printer = "Two Pilots Demo Printer";
$printer = "CutePDF Writer";
if($ph = printer_open($printer))
{

    // Set print mode to RAW and send PDF to printer


    printer_set_option($ph, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW");
    printer_set_option($ph,PRINTER_TEXT_ALIGN, PRINTER_TA_RIGHT); 
    printer_start_doc($ph, "My doc".rand(1,3));//name doc
    printer_start_page($ph);

    printer_write($ph,"Hello World !");

    printer_end_page($ph);
    printer_end_doc($ph);
    printer_close($ph);
}
else
{
    "Couldn't connect...";
};
```

Comment: To troubleshoot a blank page output, you should start by putting a small trace at the beginning of the script to see if it shows like `echo "hi";` right after the `<?php `.  If that doesn't show, you need to enable error reporting and display for your PHP script.

Comment: @Stivan He's declaring it in if condition.

Comment: I'm having this issue too, do you have solution already?

Comment: you have to delete this lines

Comment: printer_set_option($ph, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW");
printer_set_option($ph,PRINTER_TEXT_ALIGN, PRINTER_TA_RIGHT);